# Linear gradient is not working in Safari for Windows

Tags: windows, css, safari

I have been testing header of the website and I found that CSS3 linear gradient style is not working on Windows, buy in iOS and OS X is working fine.

Here is the CSS rule:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #E7E7E7 97%, #FFFFFF 98%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Following is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/76zj6sqn/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works with -webkit-linear-gradient on background-image:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #E7E7E7 97%, #FFFFFF 98%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E7E7E7 97%, #FFFFFF 98%);
```

Tested on Windows in Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari.

Comment: This is a great resource and targets most browsers too, I've been using it for years. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/